# Ubuntu 18.04 software issue, Idle ok, pycharm shows error

Tags: 18.04

Running with ubuntu 18.04
using Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux

Using ‘pycharm 2018 community edition’ as the editor.  This is the reply i get from pycharm indicating the error - as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ron/Desktop/python bible/Concrete app.py", line 39, in 
    root.mainloop()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mainloop'

Process finished with exit code 1.

When writing the program I close off with  -     root.mainloop()

However – if I run the program in IDLE, I do not get an error, the program works.

At this point i would like to mention that i have no idea where to go with this and i am a newbie when it comes to programming. This site appears to be only for people who are experienced in python, someone gave me the procedure for making a comment or raising a question, but I fear it is going to take me a while to learn this procedure. This is  possibly the wrong place for me in my early learning curve..

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the complete output (properly formatted). Your summary does not include enough information.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, you mentioned that i need to properly format my question, may i ask how do i properly format the question....?  i assume you have guidelines that i need to learn and follow?

Comment: This is the reply i get from pycharm indicating my error:                                                      
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ron/Desktop/python bible/Concrete app.py", line 39, in <module>
    root.mainloop()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mainloop'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: It does not look like a problem with PyCharm nor with Ubuntu. It's an error in your code - seems you did not define the variable 'root' properly.

Comment: to  user535733 , your comment is interesting, let me fill you in a little more. My code was written in Idle.... and when i run the code it works just fine. But when i try to run the exact same code in pycharm, it doesn't work. The code is not modified prior to using pycharm, nor is the code modified when in pycharm. Does that paint a more complete picture?